# Is there a term for a class of stochastic matrices with increasing diagonal elements?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Consider the following stochastic matrix 
\begin{align*}
A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}   
 a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots &a_{nn}\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
where, since $A$ is stochastic, all $a_{ij}>0$, $\sum_j{a_{ij}}=1$ for all $i$, and the max eigenvalue is bounded by $1$. Consider the additional property that $a_{ii}<a_{i+1,i+1}$ for each $i$. Is there a term for this additional property within the class of stochastic matrices?

Comment: Two natural questions to ask here are whether you're assuming $a_{ii}>0$ for all $i$, and whether $\sup_i a_{ii}$ is less than one.

Comment: @Math1000 thanks, I've updated the post :D